# Need library libgthread-2.0 / found lib, now getting 'wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64'

Tags: glibc, teamspeak

Trying to run a teamspeak client, getting:

```
./ts3client_linux_x86: error while loading shared libraries: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libgthread doesn't seem to be included in glibc anymore, I can't change versions of the package - too much depends on it, anywhere I can get my mitts on this file/build this file?

Comment: Found package, extracted the library, now getting `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64` I'm thinking this version of teamspeak doesn't fancy working very much.


http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libglib2.0-0

Comment: Could you edit your question (and the title) and include that information.

Comment: another issue, tried running another executable 
`./ts3client_linux_x86: error while loading shared libraries: libQtCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` This library is in the working directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Recomended method, from the repositories

You don't need for anything TeamSpeak from the download pages. The package is included in Ubuntu [multiverse repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/teamspeak-client). Just make sure that you have the repository activated and type in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install teamspeak-client
```

You might need to clean previous installations of the client. If you run into more problems you might need to [report a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

### Own your own risk, 3rd party repository

From the [TeamSpeak forums](http://forum.teamspeak.com/showthread.php/54010-Packaging-Teamspeak-3-Client-for-Ubuntu?p=351695#post351695), twprogrammers offered a method to install TeamSpeak 3 using his repositories.

**NOTICE: Under no circumstance you should add and install software from anybody you don't trust. If you are aware of the risks please continue reading. I'm in no way responsible of the *possible* damage to your system.**

The instructions offered by [twprogrammers](http://twprogrammers.com/#udr) couldn't be more clear:

1. Adding the repository to the sources:

   ```
   sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://apt.twprogrammers.com linux net' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/twprogrammers.list"
   ```

   With this we have created our list file for apt.
2. Adding the GPG key to your **trusted** keyring:

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1BCCE0BF
   ```

   In the official site they use `keyserver.twprogrammers.com` as keyserver, but it could be down any time, so I will be using Ubuntu's.
3. Update your package list and install TeamSpeack 3:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ts3-client
   ```

   Notice that the name of the package is `ts3-client`. That's all.

Comment: Great, thanks! Anyone else following this do note that the package install is not completely clean. It'll output `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/teamspeak’: File exists` which is a file created earlier in the install. Also some permission problems that I'm looking into now

Answer (score 0):

Go to that page and download the installer: http://www.drcrazy.de/2012/05/ubuntu-12-04-einfache-teamspeak3-installation/ . (Since the page is in german here is the link to the ts3_install script provided by them: http://www.drcrazy.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/ts3_install1.tar )

Afterwards just extract the fire and run the installer:

```
sudo sh ./ts3installer
```

The installation works fine and all your files are in as /opt subfolder and accessible by the menue.

If you want to update your installation go into your /opt/ts_subfolder and run

```
sudo sh ./ts3client_runscript.sh
```